# Instruments/ Leaks show [_NSCoreManagedObjectID allocateBatch:Count:]

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am getting a crash when i go back and forth in navigation controller where one has a tableview.  I used instruments to see what is going on and i see that when i go back to the first view controller i get
`[_NSCoreManagedObjectID allocateBatch:Count:]` leaks.  Here is the screenshot from Instruments [image]
The more i go back and forth the more leaks come up.  What would be the reason for this?  I set nsfetchedresultcontroller to nil in viewdidunload, but i don't set it to nil when i go between tabs.

Thanks!
UPDATE:
I did some testing and i found that if i comment

```
 Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"personCell";
    PeopleListTableViewCell *cell = (PeopleListTableViewCell *) [tableView 

    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[PeopleListTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        // Configure the cell...

          Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
           cell.personName.text = person.fullname;
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
           NSDate *tmpDate = person.dateofbirth;
            NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tmpDate];
            cell.personDateOfBirth.text = strDate;
            NSString *imgURL=[person.imageurl stringByAppendingString:@"?maxheight=120&maxwidth=156"];
            [cell.personImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

            return cell;
    }
```

The leak goes away.  I am using this tableviewcontroller as a delegate to a tableview in a different uivewcontroller.

This is how i set it when the button is clicked to show this table

```
- (void)signPeople
{
    self.signInfoView.hidden = YES;
    self.pplTableView.hidden = NO;

    self.hud = [[ATMHud alloc]initWithDelegate:self];

    [self.hud setActivity:YES];
    self.hud.shadowEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.hud.view];
    [self.hud show];

    if(!self.pplListTableViewController){
        self.pplListTableViewController = [[PeopleListTableViewController alloc]init];
    }


    self.pplListTableViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pplTableView.delegate = self.pplListTableViewController;
    self.pplTableView.dataSource = self.pplListTableViewController;
        //shows the People List 
    [self.pplListTableViewController setupFetchResultsController];
    [self.pplTableView reloadData];
    [self.pplTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES]; //scroll to top
}
```

I tried to nil out the tableview here and there and also dealloc the labels and person class nothing helps.  What could be keeping the people class from getting freed.  thanks!

Comment: post the codes that give leaks.

Comment: is there way to find out which part of the app gives these leaks.  Because it comes out when i am looking at the tableview and also when i go back to the main page.

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  After reading the tutorial still can't understand where the leak is coming from.  I updated the question with the code.  Please let me know if you have some ideas.

Comment: what I can tell from you screen shoot is that the leaks do not come from your library but from libsystem_c.dylib and CoreData. It is ok.